# Programa Pulando scanf

Tags: c, scanf

Quando estou executando o programa, começo a digitar as informações que pede, daí se eu vou escrever um nome por exemplo, e escrevo sem colocar os espaços então o programa executa normalmente, porém se eu dou um espaço ou uma virgula entre uma palavra e outra, então o programa pula os próximos scanf's de acordo com o número de espaços que eu dei.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(){
    
    char nome[40];
    char discriminacao[40];
    float valor = 0;
    char data[10];
    
        
        printf("digite o nome\n");
        scanf(" %s", nome);
        
        printf("digite a discriminação\n");
        scanf(" %s", discriminacao);
        
        printf("digite o valor\n");
        scanf(" %f", &valor);
        
        printf("digite a data\n");
        scanf(" %s", data);
        
return 0;   

}
```

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Isso é porque o espaço, assim como a quebra de linha e a tabulação, é um caractere de espaço em branco (_whitespace character_), e o `scanf` está programado para interpretá-lo como uma marca para parar a leitura.

Answer (score 1):

Esse é o comportamento esperado do `scanf`.
Para ler uma linha inteira sem parar nos espaços, tu podes usar [fgets](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/), por exemplo.

Abaixo, um exemplo de código com `fgets` que lê, de 10 em 10 chars, a entrada do teclado:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define BUFFERSIZE 10

int main() {
  char *text = calloc(1,1), buffer[BUFFERSIZE];
  printf("Escreva algo: \n");
  while( fgets(buffer, BUFFERSIZE , stdin) ) /* saida com ^D ou ^Z */
  {
    text = realloc( text, strlen(text)+1+strlen(buffer) );
    if( !text ) ... /* faça um tratamento de erro caso não consiga alocar memória aqui */
    strcat( text, buffer ); /* obs: '\n' é concatenado aqui sempre */
    printf("%s\n", buffer);
  }
  printf("\ntext:\n%s",text);
  return 0;
}
```

[Código adaptado do stackoverflow em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3919126/2405914)